# UPDATE SQL error in statement

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to use the UPDATE Statement but i Keep running into an error...
i just cant find out what i am doing wrong..

```
    Private Sub Command85_Click()
Dim sqlstrcombo83 As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim sqlstrcombo79 As String

sqlstrcombo83 = IsNull(Me.Combo83)
If sqlstrcombo83 = False Then
    sqlstrcombo83 = " tbl_Import! " & "[" & Me.Combo83 & "]"
    Else
    sqlstrcombo83 = " "
End If

sqlstrcombo79 = IsNull(Me.Combo79)
If sqlstrcombo79 = False Then
    sqlstrcombo79 = Me.Combo81 & "." & "[" & Me.Combo79 & "]"
    Else
    sqlstrcombo79 = " "
End If

With CurrentData

    For Each aob In .AllTables
    If aob.IsLoaded Then
    DoCmd.Close acTable, aob.Name, acSaveYes
    End If
    Next aob
End With

strSQL = " UPDATE " & Me.Combo81 & _
              " SET " & (sqlstrcombo79) = (sqlstrcombo83) & _
            " WHERE " & [tbl_Import]![pnr] = Me.Combo81.[pnr]        

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Sub
```

the table to be updated is taken from a Combo box (combo81).
 the field to be inserted into is combo79 and the field to be copied is combo83.
 [pnr] is common for both tables.

the code does not run... error Shows up stating object not found..

can anyone please Point out what i am doing wrong

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I see I few errors in your code, at least you are missing to scape the "=" on the update statement:

```
strSQL = " UPDATE " & Me.Combo81 & _
         " SET " & (sqlstrcombo79) &  "=" & (sqlstrcombo83) & _
         " WHERE " & [tbl_Import]![pnr] & "=" & Me.Combo81.[pnr]
```

If still fails, try to provide the value of strSQL to see what you are actually running.

Comment: Thanks Juan, i changed the SQL... i still have an error...  It is in the WHERE Statement, i think it is with the "[ ]"....... the error is MS Access cant firnd the field [....... i think it is not reading the Name of the table and field...

Comment: Can you show the complete SQL its trying to run? (the value of strSQL)

Comment: i have a msgbox to Show the SQL... but before that it Fails... and Shows the error.. the msgbox does not appear... But if I remove the WHERE Statement and run the msgbox appears...

Comment: i think Me.combobox81.[pnr]... there is something wrong here... it invalid reference...